# unexpected EOF while looking for matching

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

i've jenkins job to execute shell script but getting the error unexpected EOF while looking for matching

```
 servicedir="dir1"
 checkdir = sh(
 script: "ssh user@hostname bash -c \"' find /home -name \"${servicedir}\" | wc -l '\"",
 returnStdout: true
 )
```

return the following error

```
bash -c ''\'' find /home -name dir1'
bash: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
bash: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use triple quotes instead so you don't get tripped up with incorrectly escaping double quotes:

```
script: """ssh user@hostname bash -c 'find /home -name "${servicedir}" | wc -l'""",
```

If you want, you could also remove the `wc -l` part and just calculate the number of lines in Groovy:

```
// Run find on the remote machine and get its stdout
checkdir = sh(
    script: """ssh user@hostname bash -c 'find /home -name "${servicedir}"'""",
    returnStdout: true
)
// Compute the number of lines in the output of find
int num_lines = checkdir.count('\n')
```

Comment: thanks @Shane, but do you know why after run the shell command the log results split into two lines, so the result is not found which it should be
`+ ssh user@hostname bash -c 'find /home/ -name "dirname`
`" | wc -l '`

Comment: @fahri That's just how the output of a bash script looks when you use `set -x`, which Jenkins turns on by default.

Comment: is there another way to be execute the command in the one line?

Comment: @fahri The command *is* executing in one line. If you are asking how to change the output of bash to be just on one line, that is not possible. If it bothers you, you can calculate the number of lines produced by `find` in your Groovy code, and then you will be able to remove the `wc -l` part.